# Cannot upload a file in proctractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation, protractor

I am trying to upload a file in protractor. This seems a simple enough task, just look for the input[type"file"] element and send it the required path.

```
element(by.css('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(FILEPATH);
```

Problem is that nothing is being uploaded (the element itself is found). I've trying other solutions but I've been stuck for this issue for a while now.

Anyone here can please help me solve this issue?

Here's the relevant DOM.

```
<li class="add-image pull-left ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope" ng-model="naCtrl.galleryFilesForUpload" ngf-disabled="naCtrl.galleryFilesRemainder <= 0" ng-if="naCtrl.galleryFilesRemainder" ngf-select="" ngf-drop="" ngf-multiple="true"> <!--This input is just for the protractor tests--> <input type="file" class="hidden-file-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ngf-select="" ngf-multiple="true" ng-model="naCtrl.galleryFilesForUpload"> <div ng-click="eventHandler()" style="height:50px; width:50px;" class="add-image-svg" height="50" width="50" float="false"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 841.889 1190.551" enable-background="new 0 0 841.889 1190.551" xml:space="preserve">
<path d="M719.414,446.744l-34.391,438.855l-434.721-31.312l2.061-28.432l406.457,29.281l29.768-379.878h-39.834v-28.515H719.414z   M628.399,781.33H122.475V304.951h505.924V781.33z M602.057,679.427h-8.188c-0.084,0-1.059,0.068-2.688,0.068  c-9.439,0-42.047-1.809-72.957-24.504c-12.684-9.301-21.414-19.59-29.085-28.695c-12.183-14.41-20.522-24.297-39.806-25.549  c-19.27,1.252-27.61,11.109-39.807,25.549c-7.672,9.105-16.388,19.395-29.072,28.695c-36.283,26.607-74.864,24.504-76.465,24.406  l-155.243,0.029v75.602h453.309V679.427z M602.125,331.224H148.748v321.93h156.106c1.03,0.027,31.772,1.406,60.12-19.367  c10.164-7.463,17.488-16.096,24.546-24.463c13.269-15.691,26.941-31.869,55.498-34.612v-0.404l8.758,0.404  c28.542,2.743,42.215,18.921,55.497,34.612c7.073,8.34,14.368,17,24.546,24.463c28.668,21.037,58.965,19.422,59.299,19.395h9.008  V331.224z M219.38,461.002c0-31.703,25.786-57.475,57.488-57.475c31.689,0,57.475,25.771,57.475,57.475  s-25.786,57.475-57.475,57.475C245.193,518.476,219.38,492.677,219.38,461.002z M245.653,460.973  c0,17.209,14.006,31.202,31.215,31.202s31.202-13.993,31.202-31.202s-13.993-31.201-31.202-31.201S245.653,443.764,245.653,460.973z  "></path>
</svg></div> <div class="text">+ Add an image</div> </li>

<input type="file" class="hidden-file-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ngf-select="" ngf-multiple="true" ng-model="naCtrl.galleryFilesForUpload">
```

NOTE: Not sure if this is related, but the 'input[@type="file"]' element is marked as hidden.

NOTE2: Directly interacting with the model that is used by the input-file (I.E. `element(by.model('naCtrl.galleryFilesForUpload')).sendKeys` ), returns a '**cannot focus element**' error. Maybe this is related to the issue.

Thanks in advance, :)

Comment: Are you completely sure you are sending keys to the correct file input?

Comment: Have you tried to send the absolute path?

Comment: @alecxe yes tried an relative and absolute path. Same issue.

Comment: Hope your input element is not hidden. I see a class with name `hidden-file-input`. Make sure your input is enabled before you try to send file path to it. To wait until input is enabled use - `browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element(by.css('input[type="file"]')), 10000);` before sending path to the input element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue (it was a pain in the butt). I unhid all elements, and then clicked on the required element to focus it.

There might be a better solution, but this one works for me. Below is a code sample:

```
 browser.executeScript('window.document.getElementsByClassName(\'hidden-file-input\')[0].style.display = \'block\';').then( function(_config){

    });

      var inputGallery = element.all(by.model('naCtrl.galleryFilesForUpload')).get(1);

      inputGallery.click().sendKeys("/test.png");
```